# How to select only the visible text in textarea?

Tags: javascript, textarea

I'm trying to figure out how to select only the visible text in a textarea box. So if there is a vertical scroll bar, any text outside the textarea box's dimensions would not be selected.
I basically want to retrieve the string/value of the visible portion. How to do this?

Comment: How do you define the visibility? what if only part of a line is visible?

Comment: If it's partly visible, it doesn't need to be selected/added to the value.